# Shouldn't Merge Sort be described as O(n * log(n) + log(n))

Tags: algorithm, sorting, computer-science, mergesort

When you think about the Merge Sort you split the set ( log(n) ) and then you join it together while sorting each group (n * log(n)). In sum that should be log(n) + n * log(n).
As shown in this diagram: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#/media/File:Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg

Comment: You're missing the point of *asymptotic*. O(nlogn + logn) = O(nlogn) for the same reason that O(3x^2 + 2x - 5) is O(x^2)

Comment: The `n logn` part dominates the `logn` part, which can thus be ellided.

Comment: side note - bottom up merge sort skips the recursive splitting, instead treating an array of n elements as n runs of size 1, and starts merging immediately. Most libraries with a stable sort use some variation of bottom up merge sort.